# How do I get a web audio api oscillator to sound more than 6 times

Tags: audio

Here's the basic code:

In the html I have a button that calls playInterval.

In the script I have the playInterval script that creates and connects four oscillators, then plays two oscillators together for 1s, waits 0.5 seconds and plays the 2nd two oscillators together for 1s.

The problem is, I can't get the interval pairs to play more than 6 times. I've searched and tried everything I can think of.

I know I shouldn't have the AudioContext in the function - that's why it is being called six+ times, but it doesn't work if I take the AudioContext declaration out of the function.

I know there must be a simple solution for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code below works for the first two levels.
Also, I have had to fake a button choice with the confirm window because I couldn't figure out how to do it with regular buttons.

Note: this is being tested in Chrome.

HTML:

```
        <table border="1" cellspacing ="10" align = "left">
            <tr align = "right">
                <td>Testing Beat Speed Difference Sensitivity (BSDS) of:</td>
                <td  align = "left" id ="beatSpeedDifference"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align = "right">
                <td>Current level (out of 13 levels):</td>
                <td  align = "left" id ="currentLevel"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align = "right">
                <td>Consecutive correct answers at this BSDS:</td>
                <td  align = "left" id ="curConCorrect"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
// define and assign variables
var faster = [447.5, 447, 446.5, 446, 445.75, 445.63, 445.5, 445.4, 445.3, 445.25, 445.2, 445.15, 445.1];
var slower = [436.67, 436.43, 436.15, 435.83, 435.65, 435.56, 435.45, 435.37, 435.28, 435.24, 435.19, 435.15, 435.1];
var bsd = [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02];
var passed = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var conCorrect = 0; //concurrent correct answers
var level = 0;
var setup = 0;
var quit = 0;
var playing = 0;
var pitch;
var choice = "empty";
moveableA440 = 440;


document.getElementById("beatSpeedDifference").innerHTML = bsd[level]*100 + "%";
document.getElementById("currentLevel").innerHTML = level + 1;
document.getElementById("curConCorrect").innerHTML = conCorrect;


alert("BEAT SPEED DIFFERENCE SENSIVITY TEST. \n\
You will hear two beat speeds. \n\
The first one will be beating at 5bps. \n\
The second one will be beating faster or slower. \n\
Click OK to accept if the 2nd beat speed is faster.\n\
Click CANCEL if the 2nd beat speed is not faster than the first.");





while (quit === 0) {
    //setup chooses a new beat speed if first or previous has been answered
    if (setup === 0) {
        pitch = getPitch();
        if (pitch < 445) { // to elliminate slower BSD sounding flatter
            pitch = pitch + 5;
            moveableA440 = moveableA440 + 5;
        } 

        setup = 1;
    }


    //playing plays the two beat speeds once
    if (playing === 0) { 

        playInterval();

        playing = 1;
    }


    //Enter user choice if no choice has been made
    if (choice === "empty") {

        var r = confirm("OK = Sped Up\n\Cancel = Slowed Down");
        if (r === true) {
            choice = "faster";
        } else {
            choice = "slower";
        }



    }

    //Once choice has been made
    if (choice !== "empty") { //reset everything for next beat speed

        setup = 0; //reset for a new beat speed
        playing = 0; //reset to play new beat speed

        //Do if correct choice
        if (choice === "faster" && pitch > 445 || choice === "slower" && pitch < 445) {

            // Stop beats if user selects ok before beats finish
            constRef.stop();
            moveablePitch.stop();

            conCorrect = conCorrect + 1; //Advance and display concurrent correct choices
            document.getElementById("curConCorrect").innerHTML = conCorrect;

            //Do if three correct answers
            if (conCorrect > 2) {
                if (passed[level] === 1) { // Do if three correct and has passed this level already
                    alert("Your Beat Speed Sensitivity is " + bsd[level]*100 + "%");      
                    quit = 1; //stop script   
            }

            // Do if three correct but not passed level yet
            conCorrect = 0; //Reset concurrent correct choices
            passed[level] = 1;//record level passed

            level = level + 1; //advance and display level 
            document.getElementById("currentLevel").innerHTML = level + 1;
            document.getElementById("beatSpeedDifference").innerHTML = bsd[level]*100 + "%";


            conCorrect = 0; //reset and display conCorrect
            document.getElementById("curConCorrect").innerHTML = conCorrect;

            if (level > 12) {// No more levels
                alert("Your Beat Speed Sensitivity is " + bsd[12]*100 + "%");
                quit = 1;
            }


        };
    } else { //Do if choice is wrong

        // Stop beats if user selects ok before beats finish
            constRef.stop();
            moveablePitch.stop();

        level = level - 1;

        if (level < 0) {
            alert("Your Beat Speed Sensitivity is " + bsd[0]*100 + "%");
            quit = 1;
        }

        document.getElementById("currentLevel").innerHTML = level + 1;
        document.getElementById("beatSpeedDifference").innerHTML = bsd[level]*100 + "%";

        conCorrect = 0; //reset and display conCorrect
        document.getElementById("curConCorrect").innerHTML = conCorrect;

    }
choice = "empty" //reset choice
}

}

var r = confirm("Play Again?");
if (r === true) {
    window.location.reload()
} else {
    alert("Thanks for playing.\n\Please subscribe to howtotunepianos.com");
}



//Functions

function getPitch() {
    var coin = Math.random();

    if (coin > 0.5) {
        return faster[level];
    } else {
        return slower[level];
    }    
}



function playInterval() {

    context = new webkitAudioContext();


    // Create oscillators
    constRef = context.createOscillator();
    moveablePitch = context.createOscillator();
    a440 = context.createOscillator();
    a445 = context.createOscillator();

    // Connect to output
    constRef.connect(context.destination);
    moveablePitch.connect(context.destination);
    a440.connect(context.destination);
    a445.connect(context.destination);

    // Define values for oscillators
    constRef.type = "sine"; 
    constRef.frequency.value = moveableA440;

    moveablePitch.type = "sine";
    moveablePitch.frequency.value = pitch;  

    a440.type = "sine";
    a440.frequency.value = 440;  

    a445.type = "sine";
    a445.frequency.value = 445; 




    // Play
    a440.start(0);
    a445.start(0);
    a440.stop(1);
    a445.stop(1);

    constRef.start(1);
    moveablePitch.start(1);
    constRef.stop(2);
    moveablePitch.stop(2);

moveableA440 = 440;// reset
}
```

Comment: There's no way we'll be able to help you if you don't show us your code. Please post the relevant parts of your code, or link to jsfiddle, or something similar.

Comment: I added the full code. Hope you can help.

Comment: You definitely don't need more than 1 audio context. You should define 1 audio context in the global scope, so that all of your oscillators can connect to the same context.destination.

I know you said you tried that, and it wasn't working, but you should try to debug a solution using 1 audio context, rather than try to make it work with a large number of audio contexts.

Comment: I've tried defining the audio context outside the function and using multiple setTimeout with varying delay times for the intervals. The result is that I can get unlimited interval pairs to play, but when I try to use the confirm dialog box, it stops the program and I can't hear the intervals play until I click the box, which I don't know what to click if I can't hear the intervals :-P

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out.

I had to define the oscillator and gain as variables outside the function as well as call the audioContext.

```
var osc, oscGain
```

Then the function.

```
function playIntervals()
```

I also figured out how to use buttons instead of the clunky confirm window; each button calls it's own function.

I was using a while (quit=o) loop, but that created too many problems. Now the whole thing is done using functions.

Thanks for your help.